# How to get an Excel sheet out of the build logs

Tags: jenkins, automation

I need to automate the build status in Jenkins by generating the excel sheet out of the result.

As we are not having the command prompt access is there any plugin to generate the build status Excel report.

We need to get the actual build status (pass or fail), also need to count the build error, cmake error, and test errors present in the logs generated into the Excel report.

Answer (score 0):

You can write groovy script that uses the Apache POI libraries to create a Excel spreadsheet with build status, errors or whatever you desire.